# Get background color for Live Preview with Theme Customization API?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, custom-background

This could very well be a stupid question, but I'm working on [a WordPress theme](http://unveil.jonathanthornton.com/) (check the link to see what I'm talking about, then read on)...

You'll see the Post Formats icons are surrounded by a white circle, which has a border color matching the custom background color. I know that Live Preview includes background color by default, but I'm wondering how to change this border color with the background color, as they need to match.

Really, I just need to know what setting I need to use with `postMessage`, or if such a mechanism is possible at all.

Thanks for any and all help! I know it's a quite unique situation, since I can't find anything remotely close to the topic here, on Codex, or Google, or anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the built in custom background stuff, it's already all using postMessage.

So, just bind a function to the `background_color` message and adjust your border color accordingly.

Something like this, I expect:

```
wp.customize('background_color',function( value ) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        jQuery('whatever').css('color', to ? to : '' );
    });
});
```

Obviously, change the jQuery call in the middle to adjust whatever you're trying to adjust.

Some of the basics I didn't cover, such as hooking that JS into the previewer and such, are here:

http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/

Comment: It's working...of course it was the one setting I seemed to not try. (I even tried `backgroundcolor`!) Thanks so much for this and the incredibly helpful tutorial!