# Get entered value of customiser field for live preview

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

As per the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API), [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/get-background-color-for-live-preview-with-theme-customization-api) an probably any tutorial on the theme customiser out there, you get the value of a customiser field with the following code:

```
( function( $ ) {

    //Update site background color...
    wp.customize( 'background_color', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            $('body').css('background-color', newval );
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```

The problem is you can get that value, when its changed.

My question, is how (in a sane way) can you retrieve the value of *another* field in that same callback.

E.g.

```
( function( $ ) {

    //Update site background color...
    wp.customize( 'background_color', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            //Get value of field 'text_colour'
            //var text_colour = ??
            $('body').css('background-color', newval );
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `wp.customize( 'header_textcolor' )()`:

```
( function( $ ) {

    //Update site background color...
    wp.customize( 'background_color', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            $('body').css('background-color', newval );
            var text_colour = wp.customize( 'header_textcolor' )();
            // ... now do something with text_colour
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```